# How to configure Vim welcome message

Tags: vim

How do I configure the welcome message `...version 7.4.1689; by Bram Moolenaar et al. ...` that Vim shows, when you open a file without a filename?

Comment: Download the sources and `grep -r "; by Bram Moolenaar et al" path/to/source`?

Comment: [How can I change Vim's start or intro screen?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/627/how-can-i-change-vims-start-or-intro-screen)

Comment: Feel free to integrate that answer here, @wizzup!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question would be best asked on https://vi.stackexchange.com/ and has already an answer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really want to change that first message you need to recompile vim from source... in your source directory there is a `src/po` directory... there is every language that Vim supports, and there says every part of your welcome window.

(I'm assuming that you are using another language, but if you don't and you are native english) On every PO file there is the exact line number and file from every string in your source code, just search for every line on the welcome page and change it as you want to look.

PS. try not to add extra `\n` to that translation because this may arise some errors when you compile the sources. And pick the language that you'll use

PS2. all the initial message is in version.c  between lines 1995 and 2015